# XAMPP v3.2.1 - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi and thanks for helping.

For some reason MySQL is not working on my XAMPP, I run it as administrator in `Windows 10` and its not installed on the default "program files" folder. Here is the console error:

```
17:01:11  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
17:01:11  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:01:11  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:01:11  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:01:11  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:01:11  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
17:01:11  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

And here is the log:

```
2015-11-04 17:01:06 25a4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file E:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file E:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
151104 17:01:06 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
151104 17:01:06 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create E:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
151104 17:01:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151104 17:01:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151104 17:01:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151104 17:01:06 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151104 17:01:06 [ERROR] Aborting

151104 17:01:06 [Note] E:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You have provide the required access privileges to the directory? I am interested in: `Cannot create E:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101`?

Comment: Shouldn't running XAMPP as administrator already grant writing permission to the directory?

Comment: It actually creates the `ib_logfile101` file in the specified folder. The directory does exists and i can create files in it. I will try to reinstall, I've just recently had a port issue because MySQL was installed and jamming the port.

Comment: Hmm, you trying to run two instances of mysql at the same time?  Make sure that the XAMPP services are not enabled so that you have to explicitly start it from the `XMPP control panel. Reboot the pc and run 'netstat -a' from the CLI and check that port 3306 is not in use. Then start XAMPP from the XAMPP control panel. Delete all the existing XAMPP  logs before you reboot, will make it easier to read?

Comment: Ive uninstalled the MySQL server, will run only one server. The port is free, Iam installing the XAMPP on the suggested path now.

Comment: Reinstalling XAMPP kind of screwd the MySQL service, after reseting it the server seems to be working. I will let it run for a while to be sure. Will post back if actually works.

Comment: It worked, the problem was simply the instalation path (odd). Thanks!